# What is the proper way to link variables from different swift files?

Tags: ios, swift, oop

I have a class like this defined in the a file title ViewController.swift:

```
class Global {
    var snConnect = "1234"
}
```

I have a separate file where I want to access the variable snConnect. I am trying to access the file using this code:

```
let global = Global()
var snToConnect = global.snConnect
```

However, when I try to run this I get the following error:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'Global'
```

The Global class is defined in the ViewController for my parent app and I am trying to access the variable in a keyboard extension. These extension is a linked target to my parent app. How do I properly link variables across different swift files?

Comment: Why is `Global` inside ViewController.swift? It should be in Global.swift.

Comment: @rmaddy The file ViewController.swift contains more than one class. I do not believe I have to have a separate file for each class, correct?

Comment: No but each top level class should be in its own file. It's much easier to find things that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current vaiable should be accessed like

```
let v = ViewController.Global().snConnect
```

but it's not the proper way to have a shared value you need to make a seperate struct/class outside of any class like

```
struct Global {
  static let snConnect = "1234"
}
```

and access it like this `Global.snConnect` anywhere

**Edit:**

```
class Service {
  static let shared = Service()
  var snConnect = "1234" 
}
```

access like `Service.shared.snConnect`

Comment: The second method worked, I was getting an error that my identifier was unresolved, which I was able to solve by linking the files in target membership.

Comment: What if I want to change the value of snConnect inside my ViewController Class?

Comment: The singleton lets me change the value of snConnect but when I print(Service.shared.snConnect) in a different file, it prints 1234, not the value I changed snConnect to. Is there a way to get the most current value, not the initiated value?

Comment: make sure to change it before the next access , debug it with breakpoints/prints and verify it's a class